# How to use file_get_contents with relative paths

Tags: php

When I use this script on a page that use relative path, I can't have the page styles and images.

```
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://thewebsite.com');
echo $homepage;
```

Is there any technique to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use PHP to insert the `base` meta tag into the head of the html:

```
<base href="http://thewebsite.com/">
```

The PHP code would look something like this:

```
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://thewebsite.com');
$homepageArray = explode("<head>", $homepage);
$newHomepage = implode("<head><base href=\"http://thewebsite.com/\">",$homepageArray);
echo $newHomepage;
```

Comment: Yes.  The `base` tag changes a relative path with the absolute path.  Check out the [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base)